# Javascript arrays - issues with global scope

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out why this does not work. Items are added to the array in the first function but can't be accessed in the second (although the item added when the array is declared is there). Something to do with global scope for the array I think but I can see how to get it to work.

```js
var theArray = ["apple"];

function addValue() {
  var myValue = document.forms["myAdd"]["myInput"].value;
  theArray.push(myValue);
  alert(theArray[theArray.length - 1]);
  /*works ok*/
}

function getValue() {
  alert(theArray[theArray.length - 1]);
  /*returns 'apple', not last item pushed on array*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Array example</h1>
<form name="myAdd" onsubmit="return addValue()" method="post">
  Add to array: <input type="text" name="myInput">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<p>Get from array</p>
<form name="myGet" onsubmit="return getValue()" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Alan, welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and use the StackOverflow snippet functionality to create a runnable snippet. That way it's much easier for people to a) understand what's going on and b) answer your question.

Comment: it works correctly , whats the problem?

Comment: What is the desired output? As, if i type "orange", i get an alert saying "orange"... - which is correct, yes?

Comment: Welcome to the site @AlanJarvis - I've changed the code into a runnable snippet, for you. I added `return false` to the functions, so it doesn't try to actually submit the forms (the snippet functionality doesn't work with that). With that said, I can't seem to recreate the issue. Is it because your code *does* submit, therefore the page reloads, which then wipes the array back to only containing "apple"?

Comment: Maybe Alan isn't aware of the fact that reloading the page (or synchronously submitting a form using POST or GET) fully resets the state of all JS.

Comment: @vlaz You should not have added the `return false;` It's almost assuredly the problem and you've radically changed the meaning of the question by adding it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha thanks for the tip. I apologise and I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The default action of submitting a form is to reload the page (and if the form has an `action=` attribute, change the location to that).

Reloading the page will cause any saved values in memory (i.e. variables) to be wiped. There are ways around this, like using `localStorage`, but I suspect that you didn't intend for the default behavior of a form to take hold.

For this exact purpose, we have a [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method on the event object:

```js
var theArray = ["apple"];

var addForm = document.getElementById('add-form');
var getForm = document.getElementById('get-form');

addForm.addEventListener('submit', addValue);
getForm.addEventListener('submit', getValue);

function addValue(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stops the form submission
  var myValue = document.forms["myAdd"]["myInput"].value;
  theArray.push(myValue);
  alert(theArray[theArray.length - 1]);
}

function getValue(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(theArray[theArray.length - 1]); // Now works as expected.
}
```

```html
<h1>Array example</h1>
<form id="add-form" name="myAdd" method="post">
  Add to array: <input type="text" name="myInput">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<p>Get from array</p>
<form id="get-form" name="myGet" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Note how I removed the `onsubmit=` attribute from your form elements, it's considered bad practice to use the `on*=` attributes, because they force your code into being more global than it needs to be.

Instead, I've given them IDs to make it easy to find in the DOM (you can use any other approach, all you need is a reference to the form DOM element), and called [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on them.

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly! I was not aware the submit resets the JS variables. All the examples I could find on line just used a single function.